# Repeatedly renaming the same files in finder

Tags: mac, finder, rename, automator

I am trying to create an Automator workflow which renames all new files added to my desktop folder which do not begin with the prefix `2023` or `Home` to include the creation date in the following format `YYYYMMDD_`

The problem which I am having is the file in the desktop folder is getting repeatedly renamed. so instead of `test.txt` being renamed to `20230212_test.txt` it is continuously being renamed and prepending the date again and again so results in something like `20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_20230212_test.txt`

I have created it as a folder action as it should run for every **new** item added to the desktop. But not for existing items.

[image: Current Setup]

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. Automator seems to think the renamed file is a new file and runs again. Can't tell you why your "Filter Finder Items" isn't working. You could try replacing that filter with a bash script.

Comment: That is exactly what I think it is doing, strange that it isn't able to ignore files it has just renamed. Glad I am not the only one.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your input, after some extending searching. I found a post which recommended putting in a pause to wait while the file downloaded from an external device. [Source](http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/folder-action/index.html). Believing that the issue was caused by file still in the process of loading/saving (on the desktop) I thought to implement the same processes. It appears that a pause of 2 seconds resolves this issue. I put in a pause of 4 seconds for good measure. [image: Solution] **Note: this workaround does not work for folders or files moved to the folder by other workflows pretty much any time the file might take a bit longer to save e.g. when naming a folder***